# SQL sp_send_dbmail HTML table side by side

Tags: html, css, sql

I am trying to use HTML formatting in an sp_send_dbmail that has 2 tables that show up next to each other. I have to have a table for each one of my sets of data and I don't want the email to be to long because each tables show 1 by 1 down the email. Here is what I have currently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I made a second table that will contain the first table's information. But when I run it the overall table just contains the code from the CurrentInventoryByLocation table. What am I missing?

```
Select @CurrentInventoryByLocation = 
N'<style type="text/css">
#box-table
{
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
}
#box-table th
{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: Bold;
background: #b9c9fe;
border-right: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-left: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #9baff1;
color: #039;
}
#box-table td
{
border-right: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-left: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-bottom: 1px solid #aabcfe;
color: #669;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)   { background-color:#fff; } 
</style>'+  
N'<H4><font color="Black">By Location</H4>'+
N'<table id="box-table">'+
N'<tr><font color = "Black">
<th> Location </th>
<th> Current Inventory Value </th>
<th> Current Inventory Tons </th>
</tr>'
+ CAST ( ( 
select 
TD = LOCATION,'',
TD = left(convert(CHAR(17),cast(CURRENT_INVENTORY_VALUE as money),1),14),'',
TD = left(convert(CHAR(17),cast(CURRENT_INVENTORY_TONS as money),1),14)
from Current_Inventory_ByLocation_CTE order by current_inventory_value desc

FOR XML PATH ('tr')
) as varchar(max))
+ '</table>'

Select @OverallTable = 
N'<style type="text/css">
#box-table
{
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
}
#box-table th
{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: Bold;
background: #b9c9fe;
border-right: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-left: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #9baff1;
color: #039;
}
#box-table td
{
border-right: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-left: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-bottom: 1px solid #aabcfe;
color: #669;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)   { background-color:#fff; } 
</style>'+  
N'<H4><font color="Black">Test</H4>'+
N'<table id="box-table">'+
N'<tr><font color = "Black">
<th> Location </th>
<th> Current Inventory Value </th>
<th> Current Inventory Tons </th>
</tr>'
+ CAST ( ( 
Select
TD = @CurrentInventoryByLocation

FOR XML PATH ('tr')
) as varchar(max))
+ '</table>'
```

Comment: Have an outer table, one row, two cells put a table in each?

Comment: So am setting another table variable (like @CurrentInventoryByLocation) and creating another table and just calling that into another table?

Comment: yah one each TD in the outer table would be populated by a query that returned an other table. You could use divs and css instead, but it would still be the same principle. Outer div, containing two divs. Only other option would be one query that returned a 'join' of two queries. That might be a goer, but your name would be mud, if one of the tables changed.

Comment: I was able to get it all to show up in 1 column in the new table but its showing all the formatting code with it. It has the values and the tags in the table now.

Comment: Something wrong with the markup then. Missing start or end tag, angle brackets, quotes etc..

Comment: I made a change to the question please see above.